# C#: Show string variables in WF textboxes

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

```
 string[] board = new string[9];
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            board[i] = (textBox1.Text);
        }
```

I'm trying to make a loop which puts the text of textboxes in the array, but I can't figure out how to put the i variable in the 'textBox.Text' statement. I've tried this:

```
board[i] = ("textBox" + i + ".Text");
```

But this returns 'textBox1.Text'. How do I make the textbox.Text statement 'compatible' with the for loop?

Comment: So you have 9 text boxes and you want to write their text to array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't tell us what API are you using as [@Jeppe Stig Nielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336654/jeppe-stig-nielsen) commented.
`Asp.net`?  `WPF`?  `Windows Forms`?

In `Asp.net` you can use `FindControl` method

```
string[] board = new string[9];
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
     board[i] = ((TextBox)FindControl("textBox" + i)).Text
}
```

In `WPF` you can use `FindName` method:

```
string[] board = new string[9];
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    board[i] = ((TextBox)this.FindName("textBox" + i)).Text;
}
```

Comment: With this I get the following: "The name 'FindControl' does not exist in the current context". Do I have to 'add' this method in some way? I am very new to C Sharp.

Comment: @Ben Where are you calling this method?

Comment: @Ben Is this ASP.NET (see [`System.Web.UI.Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.aspx)) or WPF or WinForms or whatever? There are "text boxes" in many technologies.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You are very true. We didn't ask that. ))

Comment: How do I call a method? I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @Ben What type of project have you created? Web page? Dekstop App?

Comment: @Jabiyev: I made a Visual C# Windows Forms Application.

Comment: @Ben Then you can check the answer of TimSchmelter.

Answer (score 2):

Use more meaningful control names if you want to maintain your code sometime. The business logic should not be dependent on control names.

However, if you want to get an array of all textboxes in a container control like the form you could also use LINQ:

```
string[] board = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    .Where(txt => txt.Name.StartsWith("textBox"))
    .Select(txt => txt.Text)
    .ToArray();
```

If you only want to take textboxes from 1-9:

```
var txtNames = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).Select(i => "textBox" + i);
string[] board = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    .Where(txt => txtNames.Contains(txt.Name))
    .Select(txt => txt.Text)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: This answer assumes that the question is about Windows Forms and I believe that it is a good assumption.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: my experience tells me that  if   the technology is not  mentioned it's winforms. However, this approach works also with ASP.NET etc. You ned to replace `Name` with `Id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
string[] arr= new String[3];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            TextBox testTextBox = (TextBox)this.Controls["textBox" + i.ToString()];
            arr[i] = testTextBox.Text;
        }
```